# Calculation of poa from ghi,dhi,dni

Tags: python, pvlib

I am try to calculate POA using pvlib library  using these parameters (GHI,DNI,DHI,AZIMUTH,ZENITH).
I am getting good result during clear-sky but in cloudy day variation is huge. Please help me if anyone has idea related to this.

```
i=24
for j in range(i):
    Y = X[j]
    M = ['ghi','dni','dhi','zenith','azimuth','period_end','air_temp']
    values = list( map(Y.get, M) )
    df_poa = pvlib.irradiance.get_total_irradiance(
        surface_tilt=10,  # tilted 10 degrees from horizontal
        surface_azimuth=0,  # facing South                                           
        dni=values[1],
        ghi=values[0],
        dhi=values[2],
        solar_zenith=values[3],
        solar_azimuth=values[4],
        model='isotropic')
    OUT = dict(df_poa)
    Final_out = list(OUT.values())
    POA_Global = Final_out[0]
```

Comment: For a south facing surface surface_azimuth=180

Comment: I took but results not improved.

Comment: Hello @chandrakantsingh!  Your question right now is not clear.  Can you include more details about what results you expect, and the difference with what results you are getting?  Including plots or results may be helpful.